# vba code not taking correct value of a cell from file

Tags: vba, excel

This is my code:

```
    Dim RowLast As Long
    Dim sunmLast As Long
    Dim tempLast As Long
    Dim filterCriteria As String
    Dim perporig As Workbook
    Dim x As String
    tempLast = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("combine BOMs").Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("D5:G" & tempLast).ClearContents
    Range("G5:G" & tempLast).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    tempLast = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("combine BOMs").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A5:A" & tempLast).ClearContents
    tempLast = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("combine BOMs").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

'Perpetual
    Set perporig = Workbooks.Open("\\Etnfps02\vol1\DATA\Inventory\Daily tracking\perpetual.xlsx", UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
    RowLast = perporig.Sheets("perpetual").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    perporig.Sheets("perpetual").Cells(3, 1) = "Part Number"
    For i = 5 To tempLast
        Cells(i, 1) = i - 4
        perporig.Sheets("perpetual").AutoFilterMode = False
        filterCriteria = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("combine BOMs").Range("B" & i).Value
        perporig.Sheets("perpetual").Range("A3:J" & RowLast).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=filterCriteria
        Counter = perporig.Sheets("perpetual").Cells(RowLast + 1, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Counter = 3 Then
            Cells(i, 5).Value = "Not on perpetual"
        Else
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("combine BOMs").Cells(i, 5).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(perporig.Sheets("perpetual").Range("H4:H" & RowLast).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
            x = perporig.Sheets("perpetual").Cells(Cells(RowLast + 1, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 4).Value
            MsgBox x, vbOKOnly, perporig.Sheets("perpetual").Cells(RowLast + 1, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("combine BOMs").Cells(i, 4).Value = x
        End If
        perporig.Sheets("perpetual").AutoFilterMode = False
    Next
    perporig.Close savechanges:=False
```

This is the file from which I am clicking my button (or ThisWorkbook)
[image]

This is the perpetual file when it is running on the last row of data:
[image]

Notice the difference in D9280: it shows stocking type as "P" in the perpetual file, but "B" in my final result, which comes up in cell D12 in ThisWorkbook. To debug, I created a Msgbox prompt for everytime it gets that value for all rows. For every other row, it gives the correct value ("P"), but for this one, msgbox shows "B". The title of the msgbox is the row number, which shows it is taking the correct row whilr getting the value, just that I don't know why it is taking wrong value. I have tried for different data sources, it seems to be coming up with "B" in wrong places every so often.

In the code, just above the line, I have the line to get the on hand quantity, which it does take correctly (I used xltypevisible to paste values for this field, but that is only because I wanted a sum of the results and this was the only way I knew). It's only this stocking type column which shows wrong values randomly.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why you nested `cells` but `Cells(RowLast + 1`? Why the `+1`?

Comment: @findwindow rowlast+1 because I want to paste below the last row not on the last row. I added that after observing that the last entry from each file kept disappearing all the time.

Comment: But you're not pasting? I am referring to your `msgbox` line but see what user has to say below.

Comment: yes, rowlast+1 in the msgbox line was just for safety, I didn't want it to try and crtl+up from a hidden row. I don't know if I'm right but it didn't throw wrong results in the msgbox line..

Comment: @findwindow I forgot to reply to your nested cells comment. You did direct me toward the answer with your comment. The reason I have nested cells is that the inner cells() gives out the row number, I wanted last row number for the first column, and then move right and give me the value in the 4th column in the same row. Sometimes other columns have empty data, and I did not want it to affect my result. But the inner cells() did not have a sheet reference, maybe that's why it was throwing random results. I will post the answer and credit you. Thanks!

Comment: lol I didn't do much^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to findwindow, I found the answer. The .cells(cells()) part didn't have the correct sheet reference for the inner cells():

Instead of

```
        x = perporig.Sheets("perpetual").Cells(Cells(RowLast + 1, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 4).Value
        MsgBox x, vbOKOnly, perporig.Sheets("perpetual").Cells(RowLast + 1, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

I used this:

```
            With perporig.Sheets("perpetual")
                x = .Cells(.Cells(RowLast + 1, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 4).Value
                MsgBox x, vbOKOnly, .Cells(RowLast + 1, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            End With
```

And it worked.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: So "perpetual" Workbook has more than one sheet, hasn't it?

Answer (score 2):

1)

```
Cells(i, 1) = i - 4
```

as it is written , it refers to `perporig.Cells(i, 1)`
    is this what you want?

2)

```
perporig.Sheets("perpetual").Range("A3:J" & RowLast).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=filterCriteria
```

would filter from row 3, while you have headers in row 4 and data from row 5 downwards

change it to

```
 perporig.Sheets("perpetual").Range("A4:J" & RowLast).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=filterCriteria
```

3)

what do you think is `Counter` doing? Not certainly count visible rows only

Comment: 1.) That's weird, what you're saying is correct, but my Sr. No. column in ThisWorkbook is getting populated correctly. But you are right, I will make the change.

Comment: 2.) Perpetual sheet is the perporig sheet, the second picture, first picture is ThisWorkbook. The perporig sheet does start header from row 3 and data from row 4.

Comment: 3.) Counter is for not throwing an error and making it visible by entering "Not on perpetual" in my workbook if that item is not in the perporig file at all. That would have to be handled differently. I don't like to use "on error resume next" unless I'm confident I have handled all possible exceptions.

Comment: 2) I see. You're right 3) still can't grasp the use of Counter variable: how is it suppose to prevent errors and of what type/thrown by what statement?

Comment: When the filter comes up with no result, I got blank rows and I used to get errors, I forgot exactly what error, hence I did this. Plus I wanted the user to know that the value was not found in the file at all. I could say the variable is not named right, it's not really counting anything. It's just the number of rows of result that the autofilter gives out. If that is zero, the user sees Not in perpetual as the output.